# "Not all code paths return a value" C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

Hello i am currently in the infant stages of writing a petshop app on Windows phone/C#. I have made the class below to set up my generic lists and to be able to add the pets to the shop using the given fields ( Name, age, breed and type ). The problem i believe lies in the fact that i am making a display method to be called (in another page which is below called Mainpage.xaml.cs) below called DisplayShop() and i am reading in 3 strings and an int, i believe it has something to do with the fact that my DisplayShop() method is a string, although i tried to rectify the problem by converting the age field to a string in the Display() method, although this has not fixed the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink; 
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Assignment_1
{
    public class Shop
    {
        private string name;
        private int age;
        private string breed;
        private string type;

        public Shop(string Name, int Age, string breed, string Type)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Age = age;
            this.breed = breed;
            this.Type = type;
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return this.name;
            }
            set
            {
                this.name = value;
            }
        }

        public int Age
        {
            get
            {
                return this.age;
            }
            set
            {
                this.age = value;
            }
        }

        public string Breed
        {
            get
            {
                return this.breed;
            }
            set
            {
                this.breed = value;
            }
        }

        public string Type
        {
            get
            {
                return this.type;
            }
            set
            {
                this.type = value;
            }
        }

        //Create the Collection
        List<Shop> myShop = new List<Shop>();

        public String Display()
        {
            return (Name + "\n" + Age.ToString() + "\n" + Breed + "\n" + Type);
        }

        public String DisplayShop()
        {
            foreach (Shop tmp in myShop)
            {
                tmp.Display();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Mainpage.xaml.cs page

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace Assignment_1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        List<Shop> myShop = new List<Shop>();

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            setUpShop();
        }

        //Add animals to the Shop
        private void setUpShop()
        {
            myShop.Add(new Shop("John", 3 ,"Labrador", "Dog"));
            myShop.Add(new Shop("Billy", 9, "Terrier", "Dog"));
            myShop.Add(new Shop("Sam", 2, "Persian", "Cat"));
            myShop.Add(new Shop("Molly", 3, "Siamese", "Cat"));
            myShop.Add(new Shop("Nemo", 1, "Clown Fish", "Fish"));
            myShop.Add(new Shop("Dory", 1, "Palette Surgeonfish", "Fish"));
            myShop.Add(new Shop("Keith", 1, "Bearded Dragon", "Lizard"));
            myShop.Add(new Shop("Ozzy", 1, "Gecko", "Lizard"));

            imgHolder1.Items.Add(myShop[1].DisplayShop());
        } 
    }
}
```

The aim of this first part is to add the pets to an listBox in my windows app, if any of you could suggest a fix to this problem it would be much appreciated, I have included an image of the the way the phone app currently looks >>> http://gyazo.com/06217efae9265d0fef59cd2a44be7923 and the error code >>> http://gyazo.com/40c47628f1dfb7d735af4c72dde3a651
Thanks in advance,
Jason

Comment: Please use Google first.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87cz4k9t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you forgot to return value from `DisplayShop` funcion:

```
public String DisplayShop()
{
    List<string> shops = new List<string>();
    foreach (Shop tmp in myShop)
    {
        shops.Add(tmp.Display());
    }
    return string.Join(",", shops);
}
```

`Join` used here just to show the general idea, you can use whatever you want to construct the whole string.

Answer (score 3):

You  are not returning anything from this function:

```
 public String DisplayShop()
```

You should return a `string` from it, or just change return type to `void` if you don't want to return anything:

```
  public void DisplayShop()
```

Update:

```
imgHolder1.Items.Add(myShop[1].DisplayShop());
```

In this line you are calling `DisplayShop` on a `Shop` instance,but you didn't add any elements to the list that is inside of the `Shop` class.You create a seperate list.So in this case even if it works `myShop[1].DisplayShop()` won't display anything because your initial `myShop` list is empty.If you want to display one `Shop` just call your `Display` method.Anyway,probably you don't need that initial list, if you want to add all `Shops` to the `listBox` then use a simple `foreach` loop:

```
foreach(var shop in myShop)
{
    imgHolder1.Items.Add(shop.Display());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String DisplayShop()
{
    foreach (Shop tmp in myShop)
    {
        tmp.Display();
    }

}
```

your return type is a `String` but you aren't returning anything.  `Not all code paths return a value` is telling you exactly that